# How to correctly index the following?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have the following table (`file_category_tbl`) to represent connections between files and categories.

```
fileId - bigint(20)         
categoryId - bigint(20)
order - int(10)
```

So that the files in a category can be ordered, I have an order field... 
Therefore my question is what indexes would I require for optimum performance on the following:

```
SELECT * FROM file_category_tbl WHERE categoryId="3" ORDER BY order ASC
```

I have a unique index a UNIQUE (`fileId` ,`categoryId`);
As there can't be the same `fileId` with the same `categoryId`.
I have also got an index on `categoryId`, as this is what is being searched on.
I have also got an index on `order`?... but is this neccessary? as it is only doing an `orderBy` on this...

Kind Regards to any responder... J

Comment: i think a multi index on `categoryId,order` should suffice for above query

Comment: I thought that mysql didn't cared about indexes in the `ORDER BY` part. EDIT: If mysql can or cannot use indexes on the `ORDER BY` depends on a lot: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [`ORDER BY` Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> In some cases, MySQL *cannot* use indexes to resolve the **`ORDER BY`**, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the **`WHERE`** clause. These cases include the following:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the **`ORDER BY`**:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key2=constant ORDER BY key1;
>   ```

Therefore your current indexing cannot be used for performing the sort operation.  However, the same page also documents:

> The index can also be used even if the **`ORDER BY`** does not match the index exactly, as long as all of the unused portions of the index and all the extra **`ORDER BY`** columns are constants in the **`WHERE`** clause. The following queries use the index to resolve the **`ORDER BY`** part:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
>   WHERE key_part1=constant
>   ORDER BY key_part2;
> ```

Therefore a compound index over `(categoryId,order)` can be used for *both* the filter *and* the sort operations, which is the optimal outcome for this query.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, your indexing is sensible and will help towards performance of your query. But I would also suggest you to have a`Primary Key` index in your table rather than only having the combined `Unique Index`

The reason I'm telling this is, If you want to refer to any of your records of this table, may be to delete it or do any other function, a primary key would be useful. On the other hand it might actually downgrade the performance of your query because you are requiring all the fields and now with the primary key field, you have to bring in 4 fields. As a solution for that, you can specify what columns you want in your result.

Hope this makes sense :-)